# How to Expand All in the Site Hierarchy

Tags: document-library, 2007

I have a document library that has multiple levels of nested folders.  I can browse the folder levels using the Site Hierarchy component, but it requires clicking on each "plus" icon to expand each level.   Is there a way of enabling an "expand all" option in the Site Hierarchy?

Answer (score 1):

You can create or modify a view in your document library to show documents without the folders by expanding the "Folders" section and changing the "Folders or Flat" option to be "Show all items without folders".

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the list view that I want to expand.  It's the Tree view (also called the Site Hierarchy).  It's displayed to the left of the list if you enable Tree view under site settings.

Answer (score 0):

Are you browsing using the Manage Site Content and Structure, not using the standard views of the Document Library?

Comment: I'm using the standard list view of the document library.  I've enabled the "Tree view" under the Look and Feel options of the Site Settings screen.

Comment: For the quick launch?